# Error: Cannot read property send of undefined?

Tags: undefined, discord, discord.js

**Hey, i have a problem when i want to send a message to a specific user id specified in args and then i have an error, i show you it:**

The code:

```
client.on('message', message => {
            const messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
            let cmd = messageArray[0];
            let args = messageArray.slice(1);
            if (cmd == prefix + 'reserve'){
                if(message.author.id != owner) return;
                message.delete()
                const User = client.fetchUser(args);
                message.User.send("**Votre commande a été réservé avec succès par " + message.author.username + ", si votre commande a été reserver 2 fois ou vous n'avez même pas commander, merci de nous contacter en nous informant le nom du deuxième vendeur.**");
                message.author.send("***Succès !***\n**Vous avez bien reservé la commande " + args + " de " + User.username + ".**\n**Une fois que vous avez le stuff nécessaire faites ?ready " + iddumek + ".**");
                var reserver_embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                    .setAuthor("  BackGround | Market  ")
                    .setTimestamp(message.createdAt)
                        .setColor("RANDOM")
                        .addBlankField()
                        .addField("**Commande de " + message.author.username + "**", '**Articles: \n' + args + ' rubis.**\n**La commande a été reservé avec succès par ' + message.author.username + ' merci de ne pas la reservé sous peine de sanction.**')
                client.channels.get(`680899995016232970`).sendEmbed(reserver_embed);
                }       
                });
```

The error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (c:\Users\pc\Documents\Bots Discord\BackGround Market\index.js:79:30)
    at Client.emit (events.js:205:15)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (c:\Users\pc\Documents\Bots Discord\BackGround Market\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (c:\Users\pc\Documents\Bots Discord\BackGround Market\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:105:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (c:\Users\pc\Documents\Bots Discord\BackGround Market\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (c:\Users\pc\Documents\Bots Discord\BackGround Market\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (c:\Users\pc\Documents\Bots Discord\BackGround Market\node_modules\discord.js\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:200:13)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (c:\Users\pc\Documents\Bots Discord\BackGround Market\node_modules\discord.js\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:789:20)
    at Receiver.emit (events.js:200:13)
index.js:79
```

Am sorry for the english error, i'm french.
 Thank's for all helps !

Comment: Have you checked the value of `User` before calling `message.User.send` ?

Comment: Yes i sended ?reserve <id> @malarres

Comment: Not knowing what is exactly your line 79, I adventure to say that one of your `.send` is actually undefined. I think that message.author.send is working, since you have a previous message.author.id , so it must be message.User.send. Please put a console.log(message.User) before your message.User.send

Answer (score 1):

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message

```
message.User.send("...");
message.author.send("...");
```

See the documentation of discord.js. The message object has the attribute `author` but it does not have an attribute for `User`. This is why you are getting an `undefined` error.

You previously did

```
const User = client.fetchUser(args);
```

so you probably meant to write:

```
User.send("...");
```

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=fetchUser

fetchUser expects an `id` so you'll need to provide that `id` when summoning the bot via some chat command.

Comment: Don't function @Tin Nguyen the error : User.send is not a function.